# replace values of data frame column when matching value exists in 2nd data frame

Tags: r

I want to replace those values of `df1$colB` with values from  `df2$replacement` where `df1$colB` is equal to `df2$matches`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(colA = 1:10, colB = letters[1:10])

df2 <- data.frame(matches= letters[4:1], replacement= LETTERS [4:1])
```

The result should look like `df3`:

```
df3 <- data.frame(colA =1:10, colB = c(LETTERS[1:4],letters[5:10]))
```

I'd like to avoid a for-loop solution for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `chartr` function in base R.

```
# read in data with character vectors, not factors
df1 <- data.frame(colA = 1:10, colB = letters[1:10], stringsAsFactors=F)
df2 <- data.frame(matches= letters[4:1], replacement= LETTERS [4:1], stringsAsFactors=F)
df3 <- data.frame(colA =1:10, colB = c(LETTERS[1:4],letters[5:10]), stringsAsFactors=F)

# replace the characters with the desired characters
df1$colB <- chartr(paste(df2$matches, collapse=""), 
                   paste(df2$replacement, collapse=""), df1$colB)
```

According to the help file, `?chartr, the function

> Translate(s) characters in character vectors

Answer (score 3):

You can do a `merge` on `df1` and `df2`, and then replace the `colB` value by the `replacement`:

```
library(dplyr)
merge(df1, df2, by.x = "colB", by.y = "matches", all.x = T) %>% 
  mutate(colB = ifelse(!is.na(replacement), replacement, colB)) %>%  
  select(colA, colB)
   colA colB
1     1    A
2     2    B
3     3    C
4     4    D
5     5    e
6     6    f
7     7    g
8     8    h
9     9    i
10   10    j
```